# I'm unable to load cookies into a headless chrome session + selenium (MacOS)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to load cookies from a previous session into a new headless chrome session using selenium, if i try to load them using the same method i do with chrome but not in headless mode and taking a screen shot, it doesn't work because instead of being logged into the site takes me to the login screen.

I've already tried passing via Options() a cookies folder or saving them with pickle and uploading once to the site like that:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('site')

cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

driver.refresh()
```

but neither one worked.

I have already searched if anyone has ever encountered my problem, but all the question is about loading cookies with selenium in a normal chrome session.

Thanks to all reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be on another site, load cookies and then redirect to the desired page.

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('other_site')

cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

driver.get('site')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was going crazy for this.

Comment: @Michael can you upvote my answer and accept it, please? :))

Comment: Of course, but I don't have enough reputation for the upvote because I'm a newbie, sorry

Comment: @Michael no problem, hope that you enjoy that your code works now :)

Comment: @Aleksander Ikleiw - Can one add cookies to headless chrome without having to use Selenium? As in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602327/headless-chrome-sharing-credentials